# Cronómetro onFinish countDownTimer

Tags: java, android

Tengo un cronómetro que va de `15`, `25` o `35` segundos a `0` dependiendo de la velocidad que ponga el usuario en el menú. El cronómetro tiene dos botones, `start` y `stop`, con un método cada uno. El problema viene de que cuando el `countDownTimer` llega o pasa por el `onfinish()`, si yo paro el cronometro o me salgo de la aplicación, y el vuelvo a dar a `start` se queda ahí pillado, como si fuera un bucle. Sé que se queda ahí porque al acabar tengo metido un *MediaPlayer*. Dicho sonido se repite todo el rato. Me gustaría saber cómo puedo hacer para que la aplicacion no se quede en el `onFinish()`, si no que se reinicie o continúe.

```
public void StartCronometro(View v) {
    contando = true;
    cd = new CountDownTimer(tiempo, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            crono.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            tiempo = millisUntilFinished;
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            contando = false;
            play();
            cd.start();
        }

    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema que veo es que vuelves a iniciarlo cada vez que terminas con la línea `cd.start();` De esa forma te vas creando un cronómetro nuevo cada vez que usas el método `StartCronometro(View v)` que nunca paras porque lo reinicias de nuevo siempre. Deberías quitar esa línea.

Answer (score 0):

Sin duda tienes que quitar `cd.start();` del método `onFinish();`.

Sobre lo del sonido, asegúrate de liberar el MediaPlayer al salir de la aplicación, así:

```
public void onPause(){
    mediaPlayer.release();
    super.onPause();
}
```

Esto debería solucionar el problema.